# Short story by Sheckley about a man from the future who radiates love and lust

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

When I was young, I read a collection of Robert Sheckley's short stories.  I know it contained "Can you feel anything when I do this?", but that's not the story I'm looking for. It's been a long time since I read it.

I believe in the story in question, a police detective (or maybe a pair of detectives) have in custody a man who seemed to be at the center of a rash of disturbances.  Seems that everywhere the man went, people loved him or started making love to each other in public.

I believe it's implied, he comes from the future, or maybe another world, but wherever he's from, it's an utopia of love and sex.

When the detective(s) return, the man has escaped, been released by guards and officers who are now happily fornicating publicly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like it may be "The Future Lost" (1980) which appeared alongside "Can You Feel Anything When I Do This?" in *The Collected Short Fiction of Robert Sheckley* (1991). Leonard Nisher, the protagonist, travelled from the past to the future, and back to the past. He relates what happened there to a doctor.

> Nisher saw that a lot of people had  stopped. They were looking at
>   him, smiling.
>
> "Now wait just a minute," he said, automatically taking up the
>   cockroach posture.
>
> But by then a woman had hold of his leg,  and another was snuggling up
>   under his  armpit, and somebody else was pinching  his fingers. Nisher
>   got a little hysterical and  shouted at Ogun, "Why are they doing 
>   this?"
>
> "It is a spontaneous demonstration of our  great pleasure at the
>   novelty and poignancy of your presence. It happens  whenever a man
>   from the past appears  among us. We feel so sorry for him and  what he
>   has to go back to, we want to share  with him, share all the love we
>   have. And so  this happens."
>
> Nisher felt as though he were in the middle of a Cinemascope mob
>   scene set in  ancient Rome, or maybe Babylon. The  street was crowded
>   with people as far as  the eye could see, and they were all making  it
>   with one another and on top of one  another and around and under and
>   over  and in between. But what really got to  Nisher was the feeling
>   that the crowd gave  oft. It went completely beyond sex. It felt  like
>   a pure ocean of love, compassion, and  understanding. He saw Ogun's
>   face receding in a wave of bodies and called out,  "How far does
>   this thing go?”
>
> “Visitors from the past always send out  big vibrations," Ogun shouted
>   back. "This  will probably go all the way."
>
> All the way? Nisher couldn't figure out  what he was talking about.
>   Then he got it  and said, almost reverently, "Do you  mean -- planetwide?”

When the doctor is quite haunted by the story and decides to go back to ask Leonard for more, he is faced with the following scene of debauchery:

> "Where is Leonard?" cried Miles.
>
> "That guy musta hypnotized me," the  policeman said, struggling into
>   his trousers.
>
> "He preached a message of love," said  the woman from Denver, wrapping
>   herself  in Leonard's wet pack.
>
> “Where is he?” Miles shouted.
>
> White curtains flapped at the open window. Miles stared out into
>   the darkness.  Nisher had escaped. His mind inflamed by  his brief
>   vision of the future, he was sure to  be preaching his message of love
>   up and  down the country. He could be anywhere ,  Miles thought. How
>   on earth can I find him?  How can I join him?

The story can be read on the Internet Archive [here](https://archive.org/stream/The_Best_of_Omni_Science_Fiction_03_1982/The_Best_of_Omni_Science_Fiction_03_1982_djvu.txt) (transcribed) and [here](https://archive.org/stream/OMNI197908/OMNI_1980_08#page/n53) (scanned).

---

I found it by Googling `"robert sheckley" short story police detective future custody love` which yielded [this webpage](http://www.dondammassa.com/zshec.htm) on the various works by Sheckley. As it seemed to contain a brief summary for *all* his short stories, I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>ed keywords such as "love", "lust", until "sex" did the trick (*"sexual repression in 'The Future Lost,'"*).

Comment: Oh man, I was too slow. Sheckley's my favorite old school short story author. :p Best I can do now is an upvote. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This one has been taking up headspace for years!